# How can i add value inside the box in dashboard component?

Tags: reporting

Below images I marked in red box I need to display inside the bar chart.is it possible to add inside. Please can any one help me out.

[image]

Comment: By adding "Enable Hover" to the chart formatting, you get the popup.  But unlike pie-graphs, you can't make a bar-chart display the value on the graph.